# Is blender capable of adding closed captions to videos?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to include closed captions in a blender made video.  Closed captions that the end viewer can toggle on or off; NOT subtitles that are permanently on screen in the video.

There are lots of youtube tutorials on creating permanent subtitles.

The process of creating actual closed captions should be functionally similar.

If blender can't do it, are there any recommendations on how to embed CCs for uploading to more than just youtube?

Comment: I vaguely remember that Blender can export text strips as an SRT file, but I’d still recommend an external program. I currently use SubtitleEdit (via Mono on Linux), and TYLJ it works great. You can use FFMpeg to embed the subtitles (still toggleable) in the video file when you’re done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup text strips like this:

[image]

Then click View -> Export Subtitles.

After saving the file you will get srt file:

[image]

That can be used by regular video players.

Comment: Not that I use the video editor often, but I had no idea Blender supported doing this. Always discovering new things, pretty cool!